# Using Heron's formula to calculate area - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

My code:

> ```
> function calculate(sides) {
>
>   var sides = prompt("Triangle side lengths in cm
>   (number,number,number)"); //String will be size of 4
>
>   var nsides = sides.split(" "); //Splits content into array format
>   //Convert Array instances to integer values a,b,c
>
>   for(var loop=0;loop<=nsides.length;loop++)   {
>   if(nsides[loop]!=",")
>   a = nsides[loop];
>
>   if(nsides[loop]!=",")
>   b = nsides[loop];
>
>   if(nsides[loop]!=",")
>   c= nsides[loop];
>   } //End for    
>
>   //Area Calculation
>   var s = (a+b+c)*0.5 ; //represents the semiperimeter 
>   var area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*s(s-b)*(s-c)) //area calculation
>
>       //Result
>   sides = alert("The triangle's area is " + area + " square cm");
>
>
> }   //End function
>
>  //Main calculate(length);
> ```

I'm looking to set side a, b, and c to integers; however in order to do that I have to go through the array (I first converted it to an array from a string)

I'm going to add in some standard validation later; as of now I can't seem to place the values from the string entered into 3 separate integers being a b and c.

Other than that, is there a better way i can go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: better way? well, any solution is better which actually *works*. not sure what you're trying to do within the loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but is this what you're looking for?

```
var sides = prompt("Triangle side lengths in cm (number,number,number)");
var nsides = sides.split(","); 
var a = +nsides[0];
var b = +nsides[1];
var c = +nsides[2];

//Area Calculation
//...
```

Note the use of `+` to force the strings from the array into numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `+nsides[0]` etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculate() {
    var sides = prompt("Triangle side lengths in cm (number,number,number)"),
        nsides = sides.split(","),
        a = parseFloat(nsides[0]),
        b = parseFloat(nsides[1]),
        c = parseFloat(nsides[2]),
        s = (a + b + c) / 2,
        area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    alert("The triangle's area is " + area + " square cm");
    return area; // return the area
}
```

First of all I removed your parameter, it was totally unnecessary and was overwritten by the declaration of `sides` in the first line. Then I changed the split to **`,`** so it follows your instructions. Then you need to parse the string to integers using `parseInt` and specifiying the radix *10*, then you can go on with your calculations. Just a last thing, you wrote `Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*s(s-b)*(s-c))`, see that `s(s-b)` causes an exception because you are using a number to be called as a function.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input!

Everything that you said is correct and makes sense, however as for the parseInt, it won't account for floats (since one of the sides can be a float) Which means that the + unary operator would be best.

Anywho, I appreciate your comment i'm more accustomed to c/c++ so JS is a bit new to me.

Comment: You can either use `parseFloat` without a radix, it's faster than the + unary operator :)

Comment: I didn't know about the performance difference... Just [tested it](http://jsperf.com/unary-plus-versus-parsefloat), and it's true, although both are still very fast and the difference is probably negligible unless you're comparing a lot of numbers.

Comment: I haven't tested them, I just thought that the unary operator had to be slower because it needed implicit conversion to `int` or `float`, so it had to be a little slower(as the test confirmed). And yes, we're talking about milliseconds obviously :)